# Compute the total number of accepted papers that are authored by at least two authors

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

It is a conference management SQL database
The task is to compute the total number of accepted papers that are authored by at least two authors.
I am just stuck with the sum up function after group by the paper ID

```
paperparticipant
RegNum  PPNum
0001    001
0002    0
0003    0
0004    002
0005    0
0006    001
0007    0
0008    003
0009    003
0010    003
```

The above is the sample data and the table

What I want to output is just the number of 2

I can just code

```
Select Count(AuID) from paperauthorid group by PPNum having Count(AuID)>= 2
```

that it output something like

```
Count(AuID)
3
3
```

I just want to output that there are two papers (that have number of more than 2 authors)

Comment: What's with all the zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just wrap the existing query in another aggregate query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT   COUNT(AuID)
        FROM     paperauthorid
        GROUP BY PPNum 
        HAVING   COUNT(AuID)>= 2) t
```

Comment: thank you so much
but may I ask what is the t at the last stand for??

Comment: The last `t` is an alias for the subquery that you can later reference (e.g., in a `where` clause). [tag:mysql], which you're using, mandates having this alias on every subquery, even if you don't later reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM paperauthorid 
GROUP BY ppnum 
HAVING COUNT(auid)>= 2 
LIMIT 1;
```